# Does the private component of the City of London Corporation pay any tax on its financial activities?

Tags: united-kingdom, corporate-tax-laws, city-of-london

I'm referring to the privately run functions of the [City of London Corporation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_of_London_Corporation) that are exempt from public authority provisions such as the Freedom of Information Act.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CITY’S CASH
ANNUAL REPORT AND FINANCIAL STATEMENTS
FOR THE YEAR ENDED 31 MARCH 2022](https://www.cityoflondon.gov.uk/assets/about-us/budget-and-spending/city-cash-accounts-2021-22.pdf)

> The City of London Corporation is a single legal entity and
> legislation treats it as a local authority for tax purposes. VAT is
> recovered from HMRC on supplies received and paid to HMRC on supplies
> made. All transactions are therefore included without VAT. The City of
> London Corporation is exempt from income and corporation tax.
>
> City Re Limited, a wholly-owned subsidiary of the City of London
> Corporation in its City’s Cash capacity, conforms to the tax
> requirements for Guernsey companies.
>
> Barking Power Limited and Thames Power Limited are both subject to
> corporation tax, which comprises current and deferred tax. Corporation
> tax is the expected tax payable on the taxable income for the year,
> using tax rates enacted or substantively enacted at the balance sheet
> date and any adjustment to tax payable in respect of previous years.
>
> Deferred tax is recognised in respect of all timing differences that
> have originated but not reversed at the balance sheet date where
> transactions or events have occurred at that date that will result in
> an obligation to pay more, or a right to pay less tax, with the
> exception of deferred tax assets that are recognised only to the
> extent that the Directors consider that it is more likely than not
> that there will be suitable taxable profits from which the future
> reversal of the underlying timing differences can be deducted.
>
> Deferred tax is measured on an undiscounted basis at the tax rates
> that are expected to apply in the periods in which timing differences
> reverse, based on tax rates and laws enacted or substantively enacted
> at the balance sheet date.